# How to use some class in paramater template other class?

Tags: c++, templates

I have two classes `Polynom` and `Fraction`.

I need to do a template for `Polynom`, for using `Fraction` like coefficient in `Polynom`, like: `3/4 x^0 + 5\6 x^1` etc.

I understood how to use a simple type like `double` or `int`, but how to get this to work for a class I have no idea, and can't find a material on this theme.

```
class Fraction {
private:
    int numerator, denominator;
public:
    Fraction();
    Fraction(int, int);
    Fraction(int);
}
```

```
template<class T>
class PolynomT {
private:
    int degree;
    T *coef;
public:
    PolynomT();
    explicit PolynomT(int, const T * = nullptr);
    ~PolynomT();
};

template<class T>
PolynomT<T>::PolynomT(int n, const T *data): degree(n) {
    coefA = new T[degree+1];
    if (data == nullptr) {
        for (int i = 0; i < degree+1; ++i)
            coefA[i] = 0.0;
    }
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < degree + 1; ++i)
            coefA[i] = data[i];
    }
}
```

```
/*Problem here*/

int main() {

    PolynomT<Fraction> a(); // what need to pass on here in arguments?
                            // how should the constructor look like?
    /*Example*/
    PolynomT<Fraction> b(); 

    PolynomT<Fraction> c = a + b; // or something like this.
}
```

So, how to do the class constructor for `Fraction` in `PolynomT`, and how to do overloading operators for this?

Comment: Please clarify the `data == nullptr` case. Assigning `coefA[i] = 0.0;` may not work for user defined data types. For `Fraction` class, it might work. But I don't think this is a very general way to do this.

Comment: Notice that `PolynomT<Fraction> a();` is a function declaration (vexing parse). it should be `PolynomT<Fraction> a;` or `PolynomT<Fraction> a{};`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with the `coefA[i] = 0.0` assignment in the `PolynomT` constructor happens because `Fraction` does not have a constructor that takes a double, nor does it have an assignment operator that takes a double.  There are several possible solutions.

Change from raw memory management to `std::vector` for `coefA`.

```
std::vector<T> coefA;
// Then resize appropriately in the constructor
```

This would automatically fill all the elements with a default constructed object, so you wouldn't need to do anything if `data == nullptr`.

Another possibility is to change the assignment to

```
coefA[i] = T();
```

This will assign a default constructed object of the type (0.0 for doubles).

[What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading) has detailed information on overloading operators.